# OnKeyPress event is called twice using IME

Tags: .net, winforms, text, textbox, ime

I have implemented a user `Textbox` that supports text input.

If I select the IME Japanase (or other Asian input method) as my current input and enter some text, when the text is send to the control, `OnKeyPress` is called twice for each character.

In fact `ProcessKeyEventArgs` is called once with `WM_CHAR` and once with `WM_IME_CHAR`. In the end `OnKeyPress` is called twice with the same input.